# can not build debug openjdk

Tags: java-7, java

I tried to build `openjdk jdk7u40-b43` in debug mode. Build completed successfully, however when I run my application there, I get an assertion failure and following dialog opens:

```
---------------------------
AWT Assertion Failure
---------------------------
value != NULL

File '../../../src/windows/native/sun/windows/Hashtable.cpp', at line 124

GetLastError() is 0 : The operation completed successfully.



Do you want to break into the debugger?
---------------------------
Yes   No   
---------------------------
```

What could be wrong?

I used following commands to build it:

```
$ source ./config64.sh
$ ./build_openjdk_x64.sh
```

**config64.sh**

```
export ALT_FREETYPE_LIB_PATH="j:/workspaces/jdk/assets/freetype-2.4.11/objs/win64/vc2010"
export ALT_FREETYPE_HEADERS_PATH="j:/workspaces/jdk/assets/freetype-2.4.11/include"
export ALT_BOOTDIR=c:/java/java1.7.0_40

eval `./make/scripts/vsvars.sh -64 -v10`
```

**build_openjdk_x64.sh**

```
make fastdebug_build ALLOW_DOWNLOADS=true
```

build was done under `cygwin`. If I build using `make all ALLOW_DOWNLOADS=true` build completes successfully and jvm is usable, I mean it normally runs and there are no assertion failures